# Push from Private GitHub Enterprise to CodeCommit Automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, githooks, aws-codecommit

The company I work for has GitHub Enterprise setup on an internal server, so it is not accessible outside of the network. The application inside the repository is hosted on AWS, and we would like to automate the deployment.

Because AWS cannot access the GitHub Enterprise repository (as it is only accessible on the network) I was thinking I could create a hook on the GitHub Enterprise repository to push to an AWS CodeCommit repository whenever changes are merged into the master branch, essentially keeping them both synced up, and then auto-deploying from the CodeCommit repository.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need some automation on the GHE side to push the code changes to CodeCommit. [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) is a relatively new feature that can be helpful but I am not sure if it is part of the On Premise offering. Other that that simple bash scripts should be enough to get the repo across using git command line.